# Help with intermediate fields and galois group

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field

Let $E/\mathbb{Q}$ be a finite field extension. Let $F,K \subset E$ subfields which contains $\mathbb{Q}$. Let M the smallest subfield of E which contains $F$ and $K$. If $K/\mathbb{Q}$ is a Galois extension then $M/F$ and $K/(K\cap F)$ are Galois extensions and
\begin{equation}
r : Gal(M/F) → Gal(K/(K ∩ F))\\
σ → σ|_K
\end{equation}
is a well defined homomorphism.

Can you help me to prove it?

Comment: So what's the question?

Comment: @Alex how to prove it, sorry. I'm going to edit it.

Comment: @Watson I just want a hint, but I'll edit with my efforts ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$K/(K\cap F)$ is a Galois extension since $K\cap F$ is an extension of $\Bbb Q$.  Then you essentially copy the proof of the diamond isomorphism theorem from Dummit and Foote to show that the homomorphism $Aut(M/F) → Gal(K/(K ∩ F)),
σ \mapsto σ|_K
$ is well-defined, and an isomorphism.  By considering the degrees of the extensions, you conclude that $M=FK$ is a Galois extension of $F$.

Since you `just want a hint`, this should be enough; let me know if you get stuck somewhere.

Comment: I've just finished but in my language. Thank you.

Comment: Si tu quieres, yo puedo mirar a tu respuesta.  Porque la parte " show that the homomorphism ... is well-defined" requiere muchas detalles.

Comment: No, I'm fine with it. Thank you, but I need to check other dem. It's easier, but I need to be sure.